# ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, listview

Quick question. Let's say I define an `ArrayList` `bigArrayList` as a `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` . Can my `bigArrayList` contain other data types other than a `ArrayList`? Other data types like `int`, `String`, objects or a simple array?

Example code of ArrayList creation:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> smallArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    bigArrayList.add(smallArrayList);

    int myInt = 12;
    bigArrayList.add(smallArrayList); //Acceptable??
```

Also how would I go about modifying smallArrayList once it's added to bigArrayList?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tell me...What's the whole point of generics..?

Comment: try to store different data and tell us what happened..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` cannot contain other elements except `ArrayList`. You will get a compiler error if you try putting something else in.

You can, however, define the `bigArrayList` as `ArrayList bigArrayList= new ArrayList();` without any type information and you can store whatever you want in. This is very dangerous practice hence the generics.

Answer (score 2):

The point of using Generics (the "< >" thing) in collections is to tell the compiler that you are only putting a particular type (and its subclass) of objects into it. Therefore you cannot put other types into `bigArrayList`.
You could work around this by not using Generics, as darijan suggested. As he also warned, this is not recommended.

For modifying `smallArrayList` after its added into `bigArrayList`, either the code required to modify recovers the `smallArrayList`'s reference from `bigArrayList` (e.g. `bigArrayList.get(0)` and modify) or you retain the `smallArrayList` reference and pass it onto the modify code.

BTW, what are you trying to achieve with the code? What you're trying to do here is rather unusual, to say the least.

Comment: It is better practice to use a generalized generic vs. leaving out all generics.  If you really can't tell in advance what you want to put in your collection, you should use `ArrayList<Object>` in preference to `ArrayList`.